# Find image added in the column for all rows and attach click event to it

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo ui grid. I have added columns dynamically in the grid. I have created first column in the grid as below to display image in it. I am able to see the image in the grid.
I have added Column Names in the array and passed them to columns parameter in the grid

colHeader.push({ template: "" });

colHeader is array.

Based on data of the row the url to open on click of image is different.
So the only option I see is loop all the rows find the particular column then find the cell and then attach the url to the click event of the image.
Hope this makes clear. Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to iterate and modify it instead of directly generate the image with the event?

You would probably have in the grid a column definition like this:

```
columns: [
    // Your other columns
    ...
    {
        title :"Image",
        template: "<img src='my_image.gif'/>"
    },
    // More columns
    ...
];
```

modify the template and add the event handler:

```
columns: [
    // Your other columns
    ...
    {
        title :"Image",
        template: "<img src='my_image.gif' click='javascript:sayHello();'/>"
    },
    // More columns
    ...
];
```

or you can add a `class` to the image and the use that class to set the event:

```
columns: [
    // Your other columns
    ...
    {
        title :"Image",
        template: "<img src='my_image.gif' class='.ob-image'/>"
    },
    // More columns
    ...
];

// Set handler
$("#grid").on("click", ".ob-image", function() {
    alert("Hi");
});
```

See an example of both in http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/CNZrA/1/ where the third column uses the first approach and the fourth column uses the second.

Comment: Thanks OnaBai for your reply. The reason I want to loop all rows is I have created column dynamically. Now I am able to see the image in the column. On click of the image based on row values a different window will open. So what I want is loop all rows find the first column with image in it and then assign a url to open when the image is clicked. Any suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: I added the image in the column the same was as mentioned above. Although I did not added any class attribute for template, I added onclick event there itself. So the first column is the image column and the I have my 5 columns dynamically created. There are 10 rows in grid. Every onclick of image needs to open a different url/window based on a particular value from that row. So I thought if there is anyway to loop all rows find first column with image (column has no header or title) and then assign value to onclick event for it. Please any help on this.

Comment: Can you show us some code in JSFiddle/JSBin or even edit the original question so we can provide an answer that directly applies to your problem.

Comment: Regarding the row iterating and getting image from first cell how can I do that and then assign click event to it.

Comment: see your other question and my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581403/1802671

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the recommended way to do it, but I would use the web grid (as opposed to the MVC wrapper) and use a custom command column and then change the styling of the command button to use your image.

Like this:

```
 // rest of grid ommitted

        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            refresh: true,
            messages: {
             display: '{2} Items'
            }
        },
        columns: [
        {
          title: ' ',
          field: 'RowId',            
          command: [{ name: 'hmm', text: ' ', click: viewRowInfo }],
        }
     ]);
```

Then click handler:

```
function viewRowInfo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //get data item for row
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
}
```

And in stylesheet:

```
.k-grid-hmm { border:none !important; width:32px; height: 32px; background-color: transparent !important; background-image: url(icons/your-image.png) !important; }
```

When using a custom command in the grid Kendo automatically adds a class with the name '.k-grid-' + the name you specify for the command...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank Neil Hibbert for your reply. Will try this approach.