# Set title and additional properties to kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo ui grid to display data. I want to set title for the grid.Is there any way to set it.

Also I want to set some additional/custom property for grid which will help to identify the grid uniquely. Any custom property I can set to grid so I can get its value when required.

So in case if there are more instances on grid this will help.

Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating through all your tables can be done using:

```
$.each($(".k-grid"), function (idx, grid) {
    // Do whatever you want to do with "grid"
    ...
});
```

If you want to add a title, might be something like:

```
$.each($(".k-grid"), function (idx, grid) {
    $(grid).data("kendoGrid").wrapper.prepend('<div class="k-grid-header"><table><thead><tr><th class="k-header">Title</th></tr></thead></table></div>');
});
```

For setting a click event to the HTML `img` elements, you can do:

```
$("tr", ".k-grid").on("click", "img:first", function () {
    // Here "this" is the "img" on which you clicked, finding the grid is:
    var grid = $(this).closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
    console.log("grid", grid);
    // If you want to access the "id"
    console.log("id", grid.element.attr("id"));
});
```

Once you click on the first image of each row what I do in the event handler is finding the closest HTML element with `k-grid` class (the grid): this is the HTML containing the grid.

If you want to get Kendo UI `grid` element the you need to use `data("kendoGrid")`.

Simple and elegant.

In this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2qpT3/2/, if you click on "Add Titles" button you add a title to each table and if you click on "Add Handlers" and then in an image, you will get an alert with the `id` of the table that the image belongs to.

**EDIT**: If you want to iterate on every image that is in the first column, of every KendoUI grid on your document, you should do:

```
$.each($("td:first > img", ".k-grid table tbody > tr"), function (idx, elem) {
    // "elem" is the image
    console.log(idx, elem);
    // associate event
    $(elem).on("click", fnHandler);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Title is the title for the grid and not the columns. I am adding the html elements dynamically from the code. What I want is when I click the row then the row change event occurs. In that I want to get the id for the grid , because there could be multiple grids on the page. Also can I set some custom properties where I can access that value when required. Really thanks for the reply and suggestion. Please suggest on this.

Comment: Thanks for really quick reply and help. The title adding done the trick. That was great. Thanks for that.

Comment: Regarding the iterating on images I am not still getting that, as how can I iterate over rows and find first column and find the image and then attach event to it. There could be other columns in grid with images. So I only want to attach event to image in first column and assign a click event to it.

Comment: I've edited my answer for the first image of each row (also the JSFiddle example), or do you want the image(s) of the first cell of each row? Which means that if there is not image in that first cell nothing happens

Comment: Really thanks for your reply. I am looking for image in the first cell of each row. Image in the first cell will always be there for every row. Based on row values conditions I want to assign value to click event. That is the reason I want to find the image in the first cell of every row and assign event to it.

Comment: See my **EDIT** on how to do it

Comment: Really thanks for the reply. When I used the code and tried to do like this var img = elem; getAttribute("src") using the above code, I am able to get the src attribute correctly, but one query like how can I assign the click event to the image (img). Please if you can suggest on this. Really thanks for the reply and help

Comment: Do `$(elem).on("click", fnHandler);` where `fnHandler` is the name of the function or directly include the handler code: `$(elem).on("click", function() { // my code } );`

Comment: Really really thanks for the help and suggestion that you had given. I got that working. Just one query please, I am able to open respective url on click of image. But when I click on any column then the data gets sorted in the column. In that case when I click on the image nothing happens means the url is not opened. What I have done is I am doing $(document.getElementById(divId)).kendoGrid({columns:colHeader,dataSource: gridArray,sortable: true             
        }).data("kendoGrid"); and after this I am using the above code to bind url to image.After column sorting it is not working

Comment: Anytime the grid is rendered (on page, sort, read,...) means that you need to set the event again. So depending on where you set the event, you have it only for that initial render but not after sorting AND that's why I started suggesting you to set the event in the template but kept asking on iterating...

Comment: I thought of iterating because the way we were adding columns in the grid were dynamically created and as said I was not sure about how to go on this. But then in case of sorting can I again add the image navigation like this. Please if you can suggest on this. Then I think this would be finished.

Comment: Try setting the handler in the `dataBound` event of your `grid`. This event is fired anytime the grid is sorted.

Comment: Really thanks for you reply. Actually I was confused how to set it in function, I have added the code like $(elem).on("click", function() { // my code } ); so how can I put this code in the function so I can use it databound event. Please if you can help me on this.

Comment: yes. got this working. really thanks for the help. There is another issue now, but will mark this as the answer as it helped me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to change the title like this:

```
$("#grid th[data-field=Field]").html("Title");
```